# Spark: Usage of RDD Persistence in tree algorithm

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have a tree to iterate over in bottomup-order.
For example, I have a tree like:

```
 isEmpty
    |
  union
  /   \
t_m   t_n
 |     |
...   ...
 |     |
t_n+1 t_1
```

where t_i a RDD which got transformed with the usage of t_i-1. So the union function need both child RDDs. A bottomup algorithm would iterate over 
a List of: (t_1, ..., t_n, t_n+1, ..., t_m, union).

My question is, does it make sence to *persist* the RDD t_n?

Because after the calculation of t_n, many futher calculation are made (t_n+1 to t_m). If Spark caches with LRU fashion, so I think I should persist t_n.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

union is not an action operation.You should cache/persist the rdd after trigger action operation.

Comment: If the rdd contains much data and the computation consumes time,you should persist it.But cache/persist also take up resources,you must use with caution.